# Object doesn't support property or method 'after'

Tags: javascript, jquery

While adding a div tag using javaScript dynamically I have used `.after` to append a `div` after a dropdown but this does work in IE9+. In console I found  "SCRIPT438:Object doesn't support property or method 'after'". Please help me on this or suggest alternative. This works fine in `Chrome` and `Firefox`.
Thanks.

```
  var ddl1 = document.getElementById(dropdowns[i].id);
  typeErrordiv.innerHTML = "<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please select type</div>";
  ddl1.after(typeErrordiv);
```

Comment: `after` isn't supported in Internet Explorer https://caniuse.com/#search=after

Answer (score 4):

`ddl1` refers to native DOM element and they don't have [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method so error is expected. You need to create a jQuery object to use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method

```
$(ddl1).after(typeErrordiv);
```

However you can acheive it using pure native Script

```
ddl1.parentNode.insertBefore(typeErrordiv, ddl1.nextSibling);
```